# Oracle AWS package errors when removing user

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds

We are getting the folowing error when attempting to remove a user from our 11g Oracle. a dump from an Amazon DB was (failed) imported, and now we see this.

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 2
ORA-04045: errors during recompilation/revalidation of {USER}.RDSADMIN
ORA-04067: not executed, package body "{USER}.RDSADMIN" does not exist
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"{USER}.RDSADMIN"
ORA-06512: at line 2
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called:
"{USER}.RDSADMIN"
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

How do we remove this {USER} and it's RDSADMIN packages?

Thanks in advance

C

Comment: It sounds like you have a broken database (DDL) trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if user exists with same name, it doesn't throw this error. Try overriding the error using

> IMPDP with REMAP_SCHEMA option.